# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf'. using virtual environment. Flask_wtf installed - checked

Tags: flask, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, flask-wtforms, flask-login

[image]When I am trying to run my code it shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf'
Even when I checked my virtual env and Flask- WTF is installed.
Don't know what to do. Checked previous posts on Stackoverflow, didn't answer my quest.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide more data: some console logs, screenshots, your IDE configuration, python version you are using, anything. Otherwise it's just pure guessing.

Comment: It seems you are using PyCharm, so make sure the virtual environment is correct (File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter). And try launching the script without using absolute paths; using them defeats the purpose of a virtual environment a bit.

Comment: @DavidGildour I don't use pyCharm at all